# How to insert bar chart using primefaces library in eclipse with servlet java and html

Tags: servlets, primefaces, bar-chart

I want make bar chart with the numbers that I get from the web dynamic form.

I have this java code (MyServlet.java):

```
    public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public MyServlet() {
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

   PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
   String a=request.getParameter("a1");
   String b=request.getParameter("a2");
   float i=0;
   float j=0;

  try {
      i= Float.parseFloat(a);
      j= Float.parseFloat(b);
      float sum=i+j; 

        float counter1= (i*100/sum);
        float counter2= (j*100/sum);

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");

        out.println("First group is "+ df.format(counter1) +"% of sum");
         out.println("Second group is "+ df.format(counter2) +"% of sum"); 
        //out.println("Prva grupa sadrzi "+ df.format(brojacPrvi) +"% od 
          //ukupnog broja clanova. ");
         //out.println("Druga grupa sadrzi "+ df.format(brojacDrugi) +"% od 
          //ukupnog broja clanova."); 
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {

       out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
       out.println("alert('Only numbers!!!');");
       out.println("location='index.jsp';");
       out.println("</script>");

}
```

My Html code (index.jsp):

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
      <html>
      <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head>
    <body>
     <form action="MyServlet">
     <H4>Insert first number</H4>
     <hr/>
     <input type="text" name="a1" />
     <hr/>
     <H4>Insert second number</H4>
     <hr/>
     <input type="text" name="a2" />
    <hr/>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <br>

     </form>
      </body>
       </html>
```

This is how my app looks on web, I just enter two numbers:
[image]

This how it looks like when I click Submit.
[image]

So my question is how to set counter1 and counter2 in bar chart on page MyServlet.java using primefaces library. I want bar chart under the text of my second page.

Comment: Your question is indeed sort of vague. Start as @Melloware suggests

Answer (score 1):

If you intend on using Primefaces that means you are using JavaServer Faces (JSF).  A straight servlet will not do you need to use a backing bean.

I suggest just simply following the Primefaces Bar Chart example:  https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/bar.xhtml

You can clone this project https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test to get you started using Primefaces and run "mvn clean jetty:run" to run the project and hit it at localhost:8080.